# deploying scalatra onto Jetty

Tags: jetty, scalatra

How does one deploy scala or scalatra onto Jetty servlet container?  Does anyone have experience or can point me to some resources online?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using sbt, run the `package` [command](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/RunningSbt) from within the sbt shell. This will create you a war file in the target dir. You can drop that into jetty's webapps directory and configure a [context xml file](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/ContextDeployer) in its contexts directory.

If you're using maven, I believe the command you want is `mvn package`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Simple Build Tool (SBT) for your project? If you do, it's as easy as running "sbt jetty"

Check it out: http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/

Comment: I would like to deploy it onto a servlet container that's already in use.  I know for instance, if I want to add php support to jetty, i can add the quercus jar. So, I'm hoping for a similar solution for scala.  Thanks

Comment: Caveat: Running a web app inside sbt should only be used for testing purposes.  "sbt jetty" and "deployment" should not appear in the same sentence.